# Fullscreen Modal Dialog like Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, dialog, fullscreen

Anyone know some good  fullscreen dialog like solution for mobile website? I'm trying to accomplish fullscreen modal list of choice. I tried SimplyDialog2 but not working even when trying the demo from their website. The SD2 not want to show content inside the dialog.

Comment: Why don't you try make hidden div then just with onClick and then fadeIn ?

Comment: This is a solution but the user should not be able to do anything before opting any of the values ​​in the list.

Comment: I'm going to try single page application with JQuery Mobile.